# How to set and apply offset to parent order setting in bracket order for Interactive brokers python api?

Tags: interactive-brokers, tws

From TWS, I can place a bracket order where I can place the takeprofit and stoploss order with a setting "apply offset to parent order". How do one apply  same setting "apply offset to parent order" from python API while placing bracket order? My code

```
    parent.orderId = parentOrderId  
    parent.action = action
    parent.orderType = "STP LMT"
    parent.totalQuantity = quantity
    parent.auxPrice=auxPrice
    parent.lmtPrice = limitPrice  #upper price when stop trigerred
    #The parent and children orders will need this attribute set to False to prevent accidental executions.
    #The LAST CHILD will have it set to True, 
    parent.transmit = False

    takeProfit = Order()
    takeProfit.orderId = getNextOrderID()
    takeProfit.action = "SELL" if action == "BUY" else "BUY"
    takeProfit.orderType = "LMT"
    takeProfit.totalQuantity = quantity
    takeProfit.lmtPrice = takeProfitLimitPrice
    takeProfit.parentId = parentOrderId
    takeProfit.transmit = False

    stopLoss = Order()
    stopLoss.orderId = getNextOrderID()
    stopLoss.action = "SELL" if action == "BUY" else "BUY"
    stopLoss.orderType = "STP"
    #Stop trigger price
    stopLoss.auxPrice = stopLossPrice
    stopLoss.totalQuantity = quantity
    stopLoss.parentId = parentOrderId
    #In this case, the low side order will be the last child being sent. Therefore, it needs to set this attribute to True 
    #to activate all its predecessors
    stopLoss.transmit = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote to IB team. Got this reply

```
Thank you for reaching out to Interactive Brokers.The said settings are related to presets and currently, there are no APIs which can configure the said settings.
```